# '0.0' is not a valid timestamp when accessing OldValue of TClientDataSet's TDateField

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, vcl

When I use the following code in a newly inserted record in a TClientDataSet:

```
cdsMyDateField.OldValue <> Null
```

I get an EConvertError:

```
''0.0' is not a valid timestamp'.
```

Looking at Delphi's VCL's code, it tries to convert the value to TDateTime which results in this Exception because the value (Null) is an invalid DateTime, but as I'm comparing Variants I thought that it would return a variant, which would be Null in this case, but that doesn't happen, instead I get this exception.

I know that I can just check if the DataSet.State = dsInsert before comparing the values, as if the State = dsInsert every OldValue is Null, but I want to understand why the OldValue tries to convert the value instead of Just returning Null in all Fields when the State = dsInsert.

Can anyone please give me some light?

Comment: If you insist it is a bug, please QC it with the code I wrote.

--jeroen

Comment: Thanks Fabricio, already voted on it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

FWIW, I've run into this same problem and it caused me several headaches.  My opinion:  The behaviour is inconsistent so even from that reason alone I class it as a bug.  It's also a bug because raising an exception on reading a property is IMHO ridiculous and not in keeping with the intent of properties (principle of least surprise.)  I'd expect OldValue to be Unassigned, not raise an exception on read.   (Also, the fact that some issue has existed for a long time does not imply anything about whether or not it's a bug.)

**(Edit: Updating my answer with more information including our workaround.  Also posted same to the QC report: http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=73852 )**

We've also had this same problem in an app that makes heavy use of datasnap/clientdatasets.  The actual problem however is not with the clientdataset, but with the Timestamp validation routine in SysUtils that apparently erroneously validates a Timestamp with a 0.0 value as invalid.

The workaround/fix is hence to SysUtils and the validation routine, and not to Tclientdataset Specifically, in the validation routine "ValidateTimeStamp()", the Time portion is correctly compared < 0 but the Date portion is erroneously compared <= 0.

Consequently a (legitimate) 0.0 Datetime value will sometimes be converted to a Timestamp with datepart = 0, and when this value is again reverse validated (such as when the value is read from a dataset field as shown here and in the QC report), an exception is (erroneously) raised.  Hence the simple fix of changing the validation for the Date portion of the timestamp to use strict less-than, fixes the problem exposed by TClientDataset.

Here's our workaround, based on Delphi 7.1

```
(* SysUtils.pas line 10934 (Delphi 7.1)  *)
(**)(* fix - Timestamp values 0.0 erroneously designated as invalid *)
(* D7.1 *)
(* Walter Prins, originally patched May 2005, submitted 4 June 2009 *)
procedure ValidateTimeStamp(const TimeStamp: TTimeStamp);
begin
  if (TimeStamp.Time < 0) or (TimeStamp.Date < 0) then (* Changed TimeStamp.Date <= 0 to TimeStamp.Date < 0 *)
    ConvertErrorFmt(@SInvalidTimeStamp, [TimeStamp.Date, TimeStamp.Time]);
end;
```

Comment: Please link to the QC report in your answer.

Comment: Hi! Not sure about other versions, but in BDS2006 I was seeing this problem with fkDate fields instead of fkDateTime. Changing the former to the latter has made the problem go away for me.

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).

Answer (score 2):

A TDateTime in Delphi is a double, where the date is stored in the whole number portion and the time is stored in the fractional portion. So a conversion of an empty date value to 0.0 is correct, to some extent. Since the underlying field you're accessing is a TDateField (or TDateTime field), it's probably doing the conversion internally.

In addition, checking a Variant against Null isn't the proper way in Delphi any more. A Null variant is still assigned, but has the value Null, whereas an unassigned variant has no value. (Think of an SQL database NULL value). Use the VarIsNull(const V: Variant) function found in the Variants.pas unit instead; it returns true if the variant is null, false if it has any other value.

Comment: Actually, there is both VarIsNull and VarIsEmpty:

VarIsEmpty - checks if Variant is of type varEmpty (the default for Unassigned)

VarIsNull - checks if Variat is of type varNull (the default for Null)

Comment: @Jeroen: I knew that. The specific question asked, however, was about null dates.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged the code below with Debug DCUs option activated
and the weird thing is that SysUtils.ValidateTimeStamp evaluates
a TimeStamp with date = 0 to be invalid and therefore throwing a 
EConvertError exception (instead of return Null or Unassigned).

So the end result is that doing an OldValue request to a null field in
a dsInsert state is that its invalid. The variant is **NEVER** returned
so it is irrelevant if you test it with (field.OldValue <> Null) or 
VarIsNull(field.OldValue). The exception gets thrown before.

The cds_something has two fields (created at design time):

- dt_Something
- num_something

Code:

```
var
  b: TClientDataset;
begin
  b := cds_somethin;
  b.Close;
  b.CreateDataSet;
  b.Insert;
  if b.FieldByName('DT_Sometinhg').OldValue <> Null then
    ShowMessage('Something wrong!!!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Normal');

  b.Cancel;
```

Note: I messed up with the original editon of this post. This now is the
correct interpretation of what I find.

Addition: tested with some other field types (string, BCD, Float and Memo) and OldValue
is Unassigned - so the test above will evaluate to false.

Appear that ONLY TDateField and TDateTimeField show that behavior. TTimeField and TSQLTimeStamp evaluates normal - but TSQLTimeStampField.OldValue does not equal neither 
to Null or Unassigned (wtf!!)...

The snippet changed a little:

```
var
  b: TClientDataset;
begin
  b := cds_somethin;
  b.Close;
  b.CreateDataSet;
  b.Insert;
  /*
  if (b.FieldByName('DT_Something').OldValue <> Null) 
     and (b.FieldByName('DT_Something').OldValue <> Unassigned)  then
    ShowMessage('Something wrong!!!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Normal');
  */
  if (b.FieldByName('ts_Something').OldValue <> Null) 
     and (b.FieldByName('ts_Something').OldValue <> Unassigned)  then
    ShowMessage('Something wrong!!!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Normal');


  b.Cancel;
```

Where ts_Something is a TSQLTimeStampField. The fields are created at design time.

Comment: Please don't post answers to your own questions unless you're providing the answer to it. Edit your original post instead to provide more details or information. (This is not a newsgroup; it doesn't work the same way.)

Also, comparing the equality of floating point values can be deceiving. Because of the way values are represented internally, something can be the same except for a silly thing like 0.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 difference, and the comparison fails.

Please post (as an edit to your post) your actual code.

Comment: It's absolutely irrelevant the floating point comparison, as it never happens.  See the last edit of my post above.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug on Midas/TClientDataSet related to record buffers.  When you do AppendData many times, the InternalCalc fields appears as "not null" (wrong null flag in record buffer).  In Delphi 2010 we can study Midas.dll sources (.cpp files).

http://img514.imageshack.us/img514/2840/wrongnull.jpg

I am researching how to implement a solution.

Al Gonzalez.

Answer (score 0):

Got it reproduced in Delphi 2009 update 2 and Delphi 2007 as follows:

```
uses DB, DBClient;
procedure TTestForm1.TestButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
const
  SMyDateField = 'MyDateField';
  SMyIntegerField = 'MyIntegerField';
var
  MyClientDataSet: TClientDataSet;
  MyClientDataSetMyDateField: TField;
  MyClientDataSetMyIntegerField: TField;
  OldValue: Variant;
begin
  MyClientDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(Self);
  MyClientDataSet.FieldDefs.Add(SMyDateField, ftDate);
  MyClientDataSet.FieldDefs.Add(SMyIntegerField, ftInteger);
  MyClientDataSet.CreateDataSet();
  MyClientDataSetMyDateField := MyClientDataSet.FieldByName(SMyDateField);
  MyClientDataSetMyIntegerField := MyClientDataSet.FieldByName(SMyIntegerField);
  MyClientDataSet.Insert();
  OldValue := MyClientDataSetMyIntegerField.OldValue;
  OldValue := MyClientDataSetMyDateField.OldValue;
end;
```

You always get this error:

```
exception class EConvertError with message ''0.0' is not a valid timestamp'.
```

I'm not sure if this is to be regarded as a bug:

- **upon insert there is technically no OldValue, so obtaining it can raise an exception**
- MyClientDataSetMyIntegerField.OldValue returns 0, but MyClientDataSetMyDateField.OldValue raises an exception

Some more notes:

- TCustomClientDataSet.GetFieldData will get the actual underlying data
- TDataSet.DataConvert will convert the underlying data to the native data format, performing validity checks where needed

**Edit**: as a result of Fabricio's comment I have stressed that OldValue is technically invalid after an insert. So technically this might not be a bug.

His 'new evidence' can be verified by checking the VCL/RTL sources:

For fieldtypes ftDate, ftTime, ftDateTime, TDataSet.DataConvert calls its local NativeToDateTime function which fills a TimeStamp, then converts that using SysUtils.TimeStampToDateTime which in turn calls SysUtils.ValidateTimeStamp which raise an exception when the Time portion is less than zero, or the Date portion is less or equal to  zero.

The Date portion can become zero only for fieldtypes ftDate and ftDateTime (TDateField and TDateTimeField), hence only those can raise an exception.
For all other data types, NativeToDateTime will not have problems: those types all allow for a result filled with zero-bytes.

I just checked the RTL/VCL history: since Delphi 6 SysUtils.TimeStampToDateTime calls SysUtils.ValidateTimeStamp, so this behaviour has been the same since 2001.

That makes it really hard to regard this as a bug.

Comment: @Jeroen
I found new evidence that this applies only to TDateField and TDateTimeField. IMHO, it's a bug.

Comment: Is invalid only when you get an ftDate or ftDateTime? Why not the other types?

Comment: First, if it's invalid it must be invalid for ALL field types. That's make no sense the way it is now and it's not documented to be invalid (D2006, at least). 
Second, the fact that's it's being around since d6 is not a proof that's not a bug: there are/were QC reports much older than that's open or even on reported status (never opened).

Answer (score 0):

I'm using delphi 2007 with MySQL and my solution is:

In MySQL query I've used:

```
select CAST(dateField AS CHAR) from table_name
```

... using CAST I converted the field to a string value and I can test if the value is `0000-00-00` ... and after this use the real value of field.